# Swiftui - Segment picker effect

Tags: swiftui, picker, segment

So, I'm in a situation where I have a Picker with two items in it, when a item is pressed there is a effect on the Item, can I turn off that effect?

```
        Picker(selection: $pickerSelection, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(Type.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                Text(type.title)
                    .tag(type.rawValue)
            }
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

[image]

Cheers, stay save!

Comment: Which *effect* do you mean? Could you demo?

Comment: Sorry I added a demo

Comment: You can build your own view using HStack instead of using Picker

Comment: @SAndreev Yes, but what effect?

Comment: The text inside the cell is kinda wiggling when is sellected, my goal is to disable that